# Notify consumer when a queue is deleted on rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I have some clients that are connected to an exchange via `autodelete:yes`. These all are publishers and consumers. But basically for now let's assume they are publising messages. Because each client has a unique binding key I can do explicit stuff on each message on the machine that consumes these machines. Everything works fine.

Now if the clients crashed or I terminate it manually (via SIGINT, ctrl+c) then the queue get deleted. Is there any way I can notifiy the consumers on the remote machines that the queue is deleted?

I'm thinking of creating a signal handler on my client application, thus whenever I catch a SIGINT or SIGTERM, then I'll notify the remote consumer (I'll send them a message that that the queue with the unique id is going to be deleted)

Is there any other ways to do this, or is my way the correct way to do this?

Comment: Could you please clarify?  When a queue is deleted, the consumer is deleted along with it (and the accompanying channel is closed). Therefore, there should be no consumers to notify.

Comment: I'll clarified the content. Basically with consumers I meant a remote machine that is consuming from the exchange that my clients are publishing to.

Comment: You are using Fanout or Topic exchanges then?  I think you may want to provide a diagram showing your topology because it's not very clear who is publishing to where and who is consuming from where.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule in messaging, consuming applications do not care about the status of producing applications.

In RabbitMQ, producing applications may become aware of a consuming application's status by way of one of two mechanisms.  The first (and preferred) method is via a [`Dead-Letter Exchange (dlx)`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).  When your message can't be delivered (because the destination queue does not exist), it is routed here, and your application is able to pull messages off queues configured on the DLX to figure out if they didn't make it to their destination.

The second method is to set the [`Mandatory`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.publish.mandatory) flag on the message.  This will cause the broker to send the message right back to the producing application via a Basic.Return method in cases where the destination queue is no longer there.

If the above items don't meet your needs, you may want to revisit your architecture somewhat as there is probably a better way to design your application.

Comment: The Immediate message makes sense. Thanks for noticing it. I'll try it and comment back with my results.

Comment: My bad, I meant to write Mandatory.